# duplicate time data while zoom on x-axis in bar chart library mpchart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

[image: <code>x-axis duplicate values</code>]

I have added below line also to remove duplicate values.When I do pinch zoom in to the graph it start showing me the duplicate values.

```
xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
```

Comment: Thnx , save my time

Comment: got any solution for this?

Comment: Got any solution on this ?